# How can I stop rendering undefined at the first render time?

Tags: reactjs

I have this one problem that I found by trace back from component to component.

I have a `Quiz` component, which is a parent component, that will store 3 children's components, including my `Clock` component.

At first, I thought I'm doing something wrong with my Clock component so I spent days at that component to work out the interval function of that.

But what I notice later is that it always render the `undefined` first, which I still try to fix in the `Clock` component, then I remember I pass the `time` as a props from the `Quiz`, and I trace it back to `Quiz` component, and here I found that every time `Quiz` component rendering the first time, it'll get the `undefined` and then at the second render, it'll show the correct data that I want, so that's why my `Clock` component doesn't work.

So is there any way that I can get the `Quiz` component to render the data for the first time? Because I have to fetch it using Axios first then fill in the empty array state. What I want is to pass it down immediately to the Clock as props so I can use some time format (but since it undefined at first, it'll show an error immediately).

It'll always render `undefined` the first time.

[image]

Here is my code, it's quite a short and simple one, please help me and explain more about this, I meet this plenty of times but I usually don't mind it because everything else is working until I meet this situation. Thanks.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Clock from "../Clock/clock.js";
import QuizForm from "../QuizForm/quiz-form.js";
import RankList from "../RankList/ranklist.js";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Quiz(props) {
    const [dataTopic, setDataTopic] = useState([]);
    const quizID = Number(props.match.params.topicId);

    useEffect(
        () =>
            axios.get("http://localhost:3000/quiz-topics/" + quizID).then((res) => {
                setDataTopic(res.data);
            }),
        [quizID]
    );

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <Clock time={dataTopic.quiztime} />
            <QuizForm quizID={quizID} />
            <RankList quizID={quizID} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You may use conditional rendering.**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Clock from "../Clock/clock.js";
import QuizForm from "../QuizForm/quiz-form.js";
import RankList from "../RankList/ranklist.js";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Quiz(props) {
    const [dataTopic, setDataTopic] = useState([]);
    const quizID = Number(props.match.params.topicId);

    useEffect(
        () =>
            axios.get("http://localhost:3000/quiz-topics/" + quizID).then((res) => {
                setDataTopic(res.data);
            }),
        [quizID]
    );

    return (
        <div className="row">
           {dataTopic.length && <Clock time={dataTopic.quiztime} />}
            <QuizForm quizID={quizID} />
            <RankList quizID={quizID} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, yours is similar to Muthusamy's answer, but can I ask more about the {dataTopic.length} or {dataTopic.quiztime} that @Muthusamy use? If it's undefined or in any circumstance it'll not run and what circumstance it will run?

Comment: It works because in JavaScript, true && expression always evaluates to expression, and false && expression always evaluates to false.

Therefore, if the condition is true, the element right after && will appear in the output. If it is false, React will ignore and skip it.

Answer (score 1):

Your default initial state `dataTopic` is set as an empty array and hence the first render will always be done with the empty array. Hence, when you pass `{dataTopic.quiztime}` to the Clock component, it gives `undefined` only.

In case, if you don't want any sort of rendering with the empty array, then add a short circuit condition to the Clock component such that it will not render that component without any data.

`{dataTopic.quizTime && <Clock time={dataTopic.quiztime} />}`

Comment: Thanks for this, I rewrite the code inside the Clock and using console.log inside it to test the props that passing and apply this circuit condition in the Quiz, it's work, can I ask a little more, so if the dataTopic.quizTime condition is undefined or in what else condition that it'll fall out of this circuit condition?

Comment: Basically, untill and unless there is truthy value present in the `quizTime` property of the `dataTopic` object, your `Clock` component will not be called at all. So what happens is when its called for the first time itself, it means there is some sort of data present in it

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your Clock component code? It will be clear more after it.

Also, If I were you, I would try with async-await too!

Comment: Ah, I delete all the code inside that Clock component after many testing times, because of that I know that the problem is with the Quiz, not the Clock. So this is all I have left.

Comment: It will always be rendered undefined first, as the component renders first and then only useEffect hook will be called. But I understand, it will automatically get updated once the axios call is completed and result is returned. is that the behaviour?